# Cannot figure out this error with a sum

Tags: summation, fourier-series

I have this set of Fourier coefficients that I want to sum together. However, this what I have written is wrong in its last line.

I cannot figure out what is wrong with the last line, since [Mathematica](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=FullSimplify%20%282%20%28-1%29%5Ek%20sin%28%28%CF%80%20k%29%2F4%29%20cos%28%28%CF%80%20k%29%2F4%29%29%2F%28%CF%80%20k%29%20%2B%20%28%28-1%29%5Ek%20sin%28%28%CF%80%20k%29%2F4%29%20cos%28%283%20%CF%80%20k%29%2F4%29%29%2F%28%CF%80%20k%29%20%2B%20%282%20%28-1%29%5Ek%20sin%28%28%CF%80%20k%29%2F4%29%20cos%28%285%20%CF%80%20k%29%2F4%29%29%2F%28%CF%80%20k%29%20%2B%20%283%20%28-1%29%5Ek%20sin%28%28%CF%80%20k%29%2F4%29%20cos%28%287%20%CF%80%20k%29%2F4%29%29%2F%28%CF%80%20k%29) solved this.

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    &\alpha_k^j=\frac{\eta_{j}(-1)^k}{\pi k}\sin\frac{\pi k }{n}\cos(2j-1)\frac{\pi k }{n}{}\\
    &\alpha_k^1=\frac{2(-1)^k}{\pi k}\sin\frac{\pi k }{4}\cos\frac{\pi k }{4}{}\\
    &\alpha_k^2=\frac{(-1)^k}{\pi k}\sin\frac{\pi k }{4}\cos\frac{3\pi k }{4}{}\\
    &\alpha_k^3=\frac{2(-1)^k}{\pi k}\sin\frac{\pi k }{4}\cos\frac{5\pi k }{4}{}\\
    &\alpha_k^4=\frac{3(-1)^k}{\pi k}\sin\frac{\pi k }{4}\cos\frac{7\pi k }{4}{}\\
    &\alpha_k=\sum_{j=1}^4\alpha_k^j=\frac{(-1)^k}{2\pi k}\bigg(\sin\frac{k\pi}{2}-\sin\pi k + 3\sin2\pi k- \sin\frac{3k\pi}{2}\bigg)
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

Does anyone have a hint here?

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused. Why do you say the final line is wrong..?

Comment: Your last formula looks correct assuming $n=4 \land \eta_j=\{2,1,2,3\}$.

Comment: Apparently, the right "solution" is to write this as a sum of cosine terms, with the factor of sine and the fraction outside....

Comment: I mean... sure? That's also correct (and required less trigonometric gymnastics)?

Comment: Yes, I have no idea why, I think maybe the Prof wanted me to see that each of the cosine term determines the respective curvature of every interval function of that piecewise function.